# Flask Web Application Not Updating MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, deployment

### PYTHON

I'm working on a Flask web application, and I'm trying to implement a feature that allows me to edit runs for drivers and courses. I've included the relevant code, but I'm encountering an issue where my database is not updating as expected.

```py
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

def get_runs_from_database(selection_type, selected_id):
    connection = create_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    runs = []

    if selection_type == "driver":
        query = "SELECT run_num, seconds, cones, wd FROM run WHERE dr_id = %s;"
        cursor execute(query, (selected_id,))
        runs = cursor.fetchall()
    elif selection_type == "course":
        query = "SELECT run_num, seconds, cones, wd FROM run WHERE crs_id = %s;"
        cursor.execute(query, (selected_id,))
    
    close_db_connection(connection)
    return runs

@app.route('/editruns', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_runs():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        drivers = get_drivers()
        courses = get_courses()
        return render_template('editruns.html', drivers=drivers, courses=courses, runs=None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        driver_id = request.form.get('driver_id')
        course_id = request form.get('course_id')
        runs = []

        if driver_id:
            runs = get_runs_from_database("driver", driver_id)
        elif course_id:
            runs = get_runs_from_database("course", course_id)

        drivers = get_drivers()
        courses = get_courses()

        return render_template('editruns.html', drivers=drivers, courses=courses, runs=runs)

    # Handle editing and updating runs
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Check if the form data contains edited runs
        edited_runs = request.form.getlist('editedruns')
        if edited_runs:
            for run_data in edited_runs:
                run_id, run_time, cones, wd = run_data.split(',')
                # Update only the provided values, keep existing values if empty
                if run_time:
                    update_run_in_database(run_id, run_time, cones, wd)
            flash("Runs updated successfully!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('edit_runs'))

        # Check if a single run is being updated
        driver_id = request.form.get('driver_id')
        run_time = request.form.get('run_time')
        cones = request form.get('cones')
        wd = request.form.get('wd')
        # Update only the provided values, keep existing values if empty
        if run_time:
            update_run_in_database(driver_id, run_time, cones, wd)
        flash("Run updated successfully!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('edit_runs'))

    # Handle editing and updating runs in the same POST method
    # Inside the POST request handling for editing runs
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Check if the form data contains edited runs
        edited_runs = request.form.getlist('editedruns')
        if edited_runs:
            for run_data in edited_runs:
                run_id, run_time, cones, wd = run_data.split(',')
                # Update only the provided values, keep existing values if empty
                if run_time:
                    update_run_in_database(run_id, run_time, cones, wd)
            flash("Runs updated successfully!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('edit_runs'))

        # Check if a single run is being updated
        driver_id = request.form.get('driver_id')
        run_time = request form.get('run_time')
        cones = request.form.get('cones')
        wd = request form.get('wd')
        # Update only the provided values, keep existing values if empty
        if run_time:
            update_run_in_database(driver_id, run_time, cones, wd)
        flash("Run updated successfully!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('editruns'))

def get_runs(selection_type, selected_id):
    # Fetch runs based on the selection
    connection = create_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    if selection_type == "driver":
        cursor.execute("SELECT run_num, seconds, cones, wd FROM run WHERE dr_id = %s", (selected_id,))
    elif selection_type == "course":
        cursor.execute("SELECT run_num, seconds, cones, wd FROM run WHERE crs_id = %s", (selected_id,))
    runs = cursor.fetchall()
    close_db_connection(connection)
    return runs

def get_drivers():
    # Fetch drivers from the database
    connection = create_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM driver")
    drivers = cursor.fetchall()
    close_db_connection(connection)
    return drivers

def get_courses():
    # Fetch courses from the database
    connection = create_db_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM course")
    courses = cursor.fetchall()
    close_db_connection(connection)
    return courses

# Inside the function for updating run in the database

# Inside the function for updating run in the database

# Inside the function for updating run in the database

def update_run_in_database(dr_id, run_time, cones, wd):
    try:
        connection = create_db_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Define the SQL query to update the run data based on dr_id
        update_query = """
        UPDATE run
        SET seconds = %s, cones = %s, wd = %s
        WHERE dr_id = %s;
        """
        
        # Log the SQL query and query parameters before execution for debugging
        logging.info("SQL Query: %s", update_query)
        logging.info("Query Parameters: %s", (run_time, cones, wd, dr_id))
    
        # Execute the update query with the provided values in the correct order
        cursor.execute(update_query, (run_time, cones, wd, dr_id))
    
        # Log a message to indicate that the query was executed
        logging.info("Query executed successfully")
    
        # Commit the changes to the database
        connection.commit()
        
        # Log a message to indicate that the changes were committed
        logging.info("Changes committed successfully")
    
        flash("Run data updated successfully!", "success")
    except Exception as e:
        flash(f"Error: {e}", "danger")
        # Log the error message to the console for debugging
        logging.error(f"Error updating run: {e}")
    finally:
        close_db_connection(connection)
```

### HTML

```html
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h2>Edit Runs</h2>
        <form method="post" action="/editruns">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="driver_id">Select Driver:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="driver_id" name="driver_id">
                    <option value="">-- Select Driver --</option>
                    {% for driver in drivers %}
                    <option value="{{ driver.driver_id }}">{{ driver.first_name }} {{ driver.surname }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="course_id">Select Course:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="course_id" name="course_id">
                    <option value="">-- Select Course --</option>
                    {% for course in courses %}
                    <option value="{{ course.course_id }}">{{ course.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
        </form>

        {% if runs %}
        <table class="table table-striped mt-4">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Run Number</th>
                    <th>Run Time</th>
                    <th>Cones</th>
                    <th>WD</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Inside the table that displays runs -->
                {% for run in runs %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ run.run_num }}</td>
                    <td>{{ run.seconds }}</td>
                    <td>{{ run.cones }}</td>
                    <td>{{ run.wd }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="/editruns">
                            <input type="hidden" name="run_id" value="{{ run.run_id }}">
                            <input type="text" name="run_time" value="{{ run.seconds }}">
                            <input type="text" name="cones" value="{{ run.cones }}">
                            <input type="text" name="wd" value="{{ run.wd }}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update Run">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
        {% endif %}
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="flashes">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

    </div>
```

### Database

```sql
-- Table structure for table `car`

CREATE TABLE `car` (
  `car_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `drive_class` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

-- Dumping data for table `car`

INSERT INTO `car` (`car_num`, `model`, `drive_class`) VALUES


-- Table structure for table `course`

CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `course_id` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

-- Dumping data for table `course`

INSERT INTO `course` (`course_id`, `name`, `image`) VALUES


-- Table structure for table `driver`

CREATE TABLE `driver` (
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caregiver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_junior` int(1) DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

-- Dumping data for table `driver`

INSERT INTO `driver` (`driver_id`, `first_name`, `surname`, `date_of_birth`, `age`, `caregiver`, 

-- Table structure for table `run`

CREATE TABLE `run` (
  `dr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crs_id` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `run_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seconds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cones` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

-- Dumping data for table `run`

INSERT INTO `run` (`dr_id`, `crs_id`, `run_num`, `seconds`, `cones`, `wd`) VALUES
```

### Edit Runs

Enter or edit times, cones, and WD for a run. The admin will be able to select a driver and then edit any runs for that driver or select a course to edit any runs for that course. The admin should not have to re-enter any existing values that are not being entered/edited.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To better assist you, could you please share the steps you've taken to address this problem so far? Knowing what you've tried will help us provide you with more targeted and effective solutions. Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to commit if you are using SQLAlchemy and if you didn't set anything when creating the engine.

Comment: where ?? and i am using MySQL